# vacode not able to preview the icons while browsing

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

As seen in the picture I'm browsing the icons but none of them are shown. The `previewlsp` has true value but vscode can't show the icon images?

This is vscode version:

```
Version: 1.58.1
Commit: 2aeda6b18e13c4f4f9edf6667158a6b8d408874b
Date: 2021-07-13T06:20:02.397Z
Electron: 12.0.13
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.19.0-17-amd64
```

And flutter sdk:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

VS code doesn't show the icons in the suggestions. If you want to see the icons I would prefer to use the [google font icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) website. Here you can search for the icons with the name.

If you want to see font awesome icons. [Here is the link to it](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2).

Comment: I remember that vscode shown icons before.

Comment: @CyrustheGreat It doesn't show icons as long as I remember but anyways when you complete the icon command you can see the icon on the left line.